# preg_match_all parsing, only one match

Tags: php, regex, match

I have following input data(note that some of the whitespace is getting messed up):

> aggr0_howzeg253_sata online          raid_dp, aggr     root, diskroot,
>   nosnap=off, raidtype=raid_dp,
>                                   32-bit            raidsize=14, ignore_inconsistent=off,
>                                                     snapmirrored=off, resyncsnaptime=60,
>                                                     fs_size_fixed=off, snapshot_autodelete=on,
>                                                     lost_write_protect=on, ha_policy=cfo,
>                                                     hybrid_enabled=off, percent_snapshot_space=5%,
>                                                     free_space_realloc=off
>
> ```
>             Volumes: root_vol_howzeg253, howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol16_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol5_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol18_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol21_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol33_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol24_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol34_sv_mirror
>
>             Plex /aggr0_howzeg253_sata/plex0: online, normal, active
>                 RAID group /aggr0_howzeg253_sata/plex0/rg0: normal, block checksums
>                 RAID group /aggr0_howzeg253_sata/plex0/rg1: normal, block checksums
> ```
>
> aggr1_howzeg253_sata online          raid_dp, aggr     nosnap=off,
>   raidtype=raid_dp, raidsize=14,
>                                   32-bit            ignore_inconsistent=off, snapmirrored=off,
>                                                     resyncsnaptime=60, fs_size_fixed=off,
>                                                     snapshot_autodelete=on, lost_write_protect=on,
>                                                     ha_policy=cfo, hybrid_enabled=off,
>                                                     percent_snapshot_space=5%,
>                                                     free_space_realloc=off
>
> ```
>             Volumes: howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol6_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol17_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol7_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol19_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol23_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol8_sv_mirror,
>                      howzeg253_ixb_esx_vol36_sv_mirror
>
>             Plex /aggr1_howzeg253_sata/plex0: online, normal, active
>                 RAID group /aggr1_howzeg253_sata/plex0/rg0: normal, block checksums
>                 RAID group /aggr1_howzeg253_sata/plex0/rg1: normal, block checksums
> ```

I use this expression with preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all("|(aggr[a-z0-9_]+)\s+.*Volumes.\s+(.*)\s+Plex.*checksums|s", $rawdata, $out);
```

However the output that I get only gives me the information from the first block(which seems parsed correctly; each block starts with aggr_... at the beginning of a line).
I tried different ways but couldn't get what I wanted(like multiline with the carrot at the beginning of the expression, and the s modifier).

So this is the output I get:

```
...
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => aggr4_delng153_sas_sata
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => delng153_ixb_esx_vol19, delng153_ixb_esx_vol20,
                     delng153_ixb_esx_vol21, delng153_ixb_esx_vol28,
                     delng153_ixb_esx_vol29, delng153_ixb_esx_vol30,
                     delng153_ixb_esx_vol31


    )
```

I want the second block to be returned as well.
Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("|(aggr[a-z0-9_]+)\s+.*Volumes.\s+(.*)\s+Plex.*checksums|sg", $rawdata, $out);
```

The global `g` search flag makes the RegExp search for a pattern throughout the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Bro I think you are looking for this

```
'/(aggr[a-z0-9_]+)\s.*?Volumes:(.*?)rg1: normal, block checksums/s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Really stupid that I yesterday evening couldn't find it.
This morning I looked 5 minutes and was like: no, will post it.
5 minutes later I found that with using modifier U it worked.
However I'll look into your proposed solutions as well.

It seems like Naveed's answer would return to much (block until the words "block cheksums") however I might be wrong.