# PHP preg_match_all matches correctly but only gives one match

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regex to pull out sections from content submitted by a user:

```
preg_match_all("~\[section name=[\"|'](.*?)[\"|']\](.*?)\[\/section\]~", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The purpose is to allow non-technical users to easily create different named sections. As far as I can tell, PHP's bbcode parser won't allow me to pull out contents and attribute values into an array in this way.

I'm not sure why the accepted answer at [preg_match_all parsing, only one match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535553/preg-match-all-parsing-only-one-match) was accepted, because it suggests that preg_match_all doesn't globally match by default, and the suggested `g` flag seems to be invalid.

The current function correctly matches so that:

```
[section name="one"]this is section one[/section]
```

Gets put into `$matches`:

```
array (size=1)
    0 => 
        array (size=3)
            0 => string '[section name="one"]this is section one[/section]'
            1 => string 'one'
            2 => string 'this is section one'
```

This is the desired behavior.

However, it doesn't add further matches to the `$matches` array, only the first.

What do I need to do to have `$matches` populated with all the matches in the given string?

Comment: You're really getting lucky with your escaping and use of `|`, `[]`. You should take some time to learn the right way to use those.

Comment: @pguardiario Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well for example ("|') is an alternation group. You 're using ["|'] which is a character class with a literal | in it. If you left the | out it would do the same thing as ("|'). Also you're escaping /, which is important when you're using / as a delimiter but otherwise unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange, because when I run the script:

```
    $content = '[section name="one"]this is section one[/section]<br />[section name="two"]this is section two[/section]';
    preg_match_all("~\[section name=[\"|'](.*?)[\"|']\](.*?)\[\/section\]~", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    print_r($matches);
```

It prints:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => [section name="one"]this is section one[/section]
        [1] => one
        [2] => this is section one
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => [section name="two"]this is section two[/section]
        [1] => two
        [2] => this is section two
    )

)
```

Comment: The problem was the content contained whitespace (newlines) which wasn't covered by `.*` in the regex. Updated regex pattern is:

`~\[section name=[\"|'](.*?)[\"|']\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/section\]~`

This allows whitespace in the content and finds all matches correctly.

Your answer with the input on one line prompted me to consider this problem.

Comment: Glad I could help in any way.